# keyerror in simple dataset regplot - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'conjugate'

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am creating this data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

data = np.array([['', 'Gross ', 'Target'],
                 [0, 728, 500],
                 [1, 701, 750],
                 [2, 590, 570],
                 [3, 548, 596]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:, 1:], columns=data[0, 1:])
df

    Gross   Target
0   728     500
1   701     750
2   590     570
3   548     596
```

and trying to plot:

```
sns.regplot(x='Gross', y='Target', data=df)
```

results in: `KeyError: 'Gross'`

--- UPDATE ---

After fixing the whitespace , I am receiving:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'conjugate'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `whitespace` in string, which is converted to column:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
['Gross ', 'Target']
```

One possible solution is [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
print (df.columns.tolist())
['Gross', 'Target']
```

Or add whitespace to column name:

```
sns.regplot(x='Gross ', y='Target', data=df)
```

---

```
print (df.dtypes)
Gross     object
Target    object
dtype: object

sns.regplot(x='Gross', y='Target', data=df.astype(int))
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Hmm.I didn't notice,thanks.But, now it gives me : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'conjugate'`

Comment: It seems you have older version of pandas. What is your version?

Comment: I am using 0.19.2

Comment: Maybe help cast to str first `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.strip()`

Comment: It still gives me the same error.Does it work to you?

Comment: Hmmm, problem is in `sns.regplot(x='Gross', y='Target', data=df)` or in `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` ?

Comment: It is when I call `sns.regplot`

Comment: I got it need convert to `int` - `sns.regplot(x='Gross', y='Target', data=df.astype(int))`

Comment: because if check `print (df.dtypes)` it return `objects` for all columns instead `int`

Comment: Hmm.Thanks!So, when I create the table do I have to define manually every column data type?(upvoted)

Comment: I think it depends of your construction of df. If check `print (data)`, numpy convert all values to strings.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the array `data`, numpy converts the numbers to strings. seaborn is trying to do math with these strings, and it doesn't work. If you put the column headings in one array and the numbers in another, it will work.